# Return different types of Lists<> in Method (C#)

Tags: c#

At the moment I have a Method for executing database calls which returns a `DataTable` which is then converted into a `List<>`. Since I am using this Method for different database calls I need to make it return any `List<>`. This is at the moment not possible since I get an error:

```
Cannot convert List<T> to List<object>
```

What return type should the function have if i want to return any list?
e.g. it could be that the result list is of the type:

```
List<MirrorDeployments>
```

or:

```
List<ProductionDeployments>
```

**My Function**

```
public List<T> Execute<T>(string strSql, List<T> list)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
    {
        using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
        {
            objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
            conn.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null)
            {

                list = ConvertToList(dt, list).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: The ConvertToList method should be generic as well: `ConvertToList<T>(dt, list)`

Comment: Also, from the code it seems like the `ConvertToList` returns an `IEnumerable`, not a `List`. Kinda silly to have a `ConvertToList().ToList()`, don't you think?

Comment: How does this differ from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240066/listt-to-listobject)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<T> to List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240066/listt-to-listobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `ConvertToList` returns an enumerable of `object`:

```
public List<T> Execute<T>(string strSql)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
    {
        using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
        {
            objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
            conn.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null)
            {

                return ConvertToList(dt).Cast<T>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    return new List<T>();
}
```

I have removed the parameter `list` because seems useless.

A better option is to convert `ConvertToList` in a generic method `ConvertToList<T>` which does what its name say.

Comment: You have removed the param `list` but you use it in `ConvertToList(dt, list)`. So maybe you should add a line `List<T> list = new List<T>();` or so?