# Function which can return any type of list

Tags: c#, list

I am programming a function where a `DataTable` is given into and the function should recognize the type and convert the datatable to a list of its type. But my problem is that whenever i return the list i get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<ADMPortal_2.Modles.ProductionPending>'
```

> to

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

Now how is it possible to create a function which can return any type of `list<>`?

e.g.

```
List<ProductionPending>
List<ProductionRecent>
List<MirrorDeployments>
```

**Function**

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, int listType)
    {

        if (listType == 1)
        {
            List<ProductionPending> list = new List<ProductionPending>();
            list = ConvertToProductionPending(dt);
            return list; 
        }
        else if (listType == 2)
        {
            List<ProductionRecent> list = new List<ProductionRecent>();
            ConvertToProductionRecent(dt);
            return list; 
        }
        else if (listType == 3)
        {
            List<MirrorDeployments> list = new List<MirrorDeployments>();
            list = ConvertToMirror(dt);
            return list; 
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**Calling the function**

The following code is the classic way of calling the function above.

```
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
        {
            using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
                conn.Open();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt != null)
                {

                    list = ConvertToList<T>(dt, 1).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're "pseudotyping" your function by using `int listType`, therefore defeating the purpose of your function being generic.

Comment: i agree with @IanA.B.King. Can you please post on how you are calling this method. most probably there might be some issue with the caller

Comment: Doing `list = (List<T>)(object)ConvertToProductionPending(dt);` works, but the comments above are probably worth running down.

Comment: Consider how much of your function is actually used in any particular invocation. Is there really something to make this useful versus just creating 3 separate functions? Even if `listType` is parameterised rather than constant, what is the variable that you assign the return from this function typed as?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a DataTable into a generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list)

Comment: Probably the way to go is to have a common interface all your three classes implement and that yun can use as generic constraint. If there´s no way of having such a common interface then there is indeed little use for a single method operating on two completely different types.

Comment: Do your three types have a common baseclass? If not, what is the caller supposed to do with the return value, not knowing what it actually is?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so you suggest creating 3 separate functions instead of doing it all in one handler? So I dont have to worry about the list types

Comment: Yeap, all your classes seem to have nothing in common. Why put it all into a single method that does completely different things depending on the actual type?

Comment: @nvoigt yes, they have a base class

Comment: Basically, you would want to use linq and reflection for this. Luckily for you, some talented people have done this before and you can use their code - basically, every ORM can get results from a database and return an `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`. Take a look at Dapper, for instance - and you might never have to work directly with data tables again.

Comment: @HimBromBeere okay, im just trying to convert the datatable to the list of the corresponding type. but your right thats different for each list type

Comment: @Gucci - I'm saying that in your example, you already effectively have 3 different functions - you're running completely different code depending on what the `listType` parameter is, so you effectively have three functions, just with an awkward calling convention and an awkward to deal with return type. If there is some common functionality, that may belong in a single function but that may be more of a helper for these three functions rather than the endpoint you expose to consumers.

Comment: @Gucci please ignore all of the posted answers and listen to Damien_The_Unbeliever and HimBromBeere instead.

Comment: And @ZoharPeled actually, who is the only person so far who has touched on what you probably actually need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return different types of Lists<> in Method (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242576/return-different-types-of-lists-in-method-c)

Comment: How is this different to your last two questions asking the same thing?

Comment: Wow, three questions to the same problem from the same person in two days. Instead of asking the same question again and again you should come to the point of your actual problem. And why the already posted solutions didn´t seem to work for you.

Comment: BTW, the fact that your method does different things for different types probably means it shouldn't be a generic method in the first place - The point of generics is to allow you to write a single block of code that can work the same for different types. Also, your `listType` is redundant and potentially dangerous - If you continue to use different methods for different types, at least use `typeof(T)` . I mean, what's stopping the calling code to do something like this? `var list = ConvertToList<MirrorDeployments>(dt, 1);` If this method could compile, this would throw a run time exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your approach is that your types don´t have much in common. Only because of some class have some inheritance-relation doesn´t mean a list of that class has the same relation. In other words: a `List<Derived>` is *not* convertible to `List<Base>`.

You could achieve this if a `List<T>` was co-variant - which it is not for the following reason. Imagine a client of your `ConvertToList`-method does something like this:

```
var list = ConvertToList<MyBaseClass>(theTable, 1)
```

Now you could also do the following:

```
list.Add(new ProductionRecent());
```

which is probably not what you want. Thus you need some collection that is *read-only*, which means you can´t add instances to it. Therefor the `IEnumerable<T>`-interface *is* co-variant and can be used as return-type for your method.

Comment: I think this comes closer than the other answers but still leans on the assumption that `IEnumerable<T>` is an appropriate return type for the use case - my guess would be that in reality what really needs to happen is some reflection-based mapping and casting to the appropriate return type since this really looks like a crude ORM implementation. I think we have an XY problem here and having lots of answers that make the code work but don't really solve the problem isn't super-productive.

Comment: @AntP Good point. I agree that this doesn´t really anser the *actual* problem of the OP, which can hardly be guessed. My answer shows some points on what OP should think about when trying to implement it this way. However it´s simply too long for a comment and wouldn´t fit well in this format also.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is using `out` keyword in its generic type, so you can use derived types in return. So how about something like this:

```
        public static IEnumerable<IBase> ConvertToList(int listType)
    {

        if (listType == 1)
        {
            var list = new List<ClassA>();
            ...
            return list;
        }
        if (listType == 2)
        {
            var list = new List<ClassB>();
            ...
            return list;
        }
        if (listType == 3)
        {
            var list = new List<ClassC>();
            ...
            return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class ClassA : IBase
{ }
public class ClassB : IBase
{ }
public class ClassC : IBase
{ }
public interface IBase
{ }
```

More info here: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Answer (score 0):

As you said they have a common base class:

```
public List<CommonBaseClass> ConvertToList(DataTable dt, int listType)
{
    var result = List<CommonBaseClass>();

    if (listType == 1)
    {
        result.AddRange(ConvertToProductionPending(dt));
    }
    else if (listType == 2)
    {
        result.AddRange(ConvertToProductionRecent(dt));
    }
    else if (listType == 3)
    {
        result.AddRange(ConvertToMirror(dt));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How do you know this is an appropriate solution with no information on how this will be consumed?

Comment: @Ant it's pretty obvious, in programming you can look at function signatures and know what the calling code should look like. Also the error is a smoking gun.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I appreciate the passive aggressive sarcasm but the point is this - the original attempt was generic, which alludes to the fact that probably the consumer is looking to deal with a specific subtype of `CommonBaseClass`, which would then require downcasting following implementing this solution. This is almost definitely the wrong solution to the problem, which is almost definitely that this shouldn't be a single method. It's pretty obvious.